# hat not big enough

Tags: output-formatting, formatting

I like to use Mathematica text cells for creating draft technical documents. When entering equations in a text cell, the ^ (hat accent) does not dynamically adjust its size to fit. It looks good if you enter x^, but if you wanted abc^, the ^ covers only the b. Anyone know how to make the ^ (and other accents) adjust to the size of the text?

Comment: Don't know how to do it automatically. You can change the font size of the hat when you use the upper script (ctrl-7). Still much work when you have to type the hat alot.

Comment: Good question: how to create a custom extensible character

Comment: Okay, someone [had to do it](http://www.villagehatshop.com/jack_stretcher.html).

Answer (score 16):

This answer is just a quick hack. I think that to make true extensible character might not be something that an end-user can do...

Anyway, redefine the formatting for `OverHat` using

```
OverHat /: MakeBoxes[OverHat[a_], form_] := 
 With[{s = First[Rasterize[a, "RasterSize"]], 
   ab = MakeBoxes[a]}, With[{sl = N[2 Log[2 s]]},
   InterpretationBox[OverscriptBox[ab, 
     TagBox[GraphicsBox[LineBox[{{-s, 0}, {0, sl}, {s, 0}}], 
       ImageSize -> {s, Automatic}], "LongOverHat", 
      Selectable -> False]], OverHat[a]]]]
```

Then, just type in the expression as per normal, e.g., 
[image: abc 1],
and then select the `OverHat` expression and reformat the boxes using the menu command `Cell > Convert To > Standard From` 
(which can also be done using the shortcut 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>) to get 
[image: abc 2]. The `FullForm` of this expression is `OverHat[abc]`.

Here's an example showing how the modified `OverHat` scales for longer expressions

[image: Powers of ten]

The `MakeBoxes` command also works with `TraditionalForm` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>), but you might want to modify it to include an 
`AdjustmentBox[..., BoxBaselineShift -> b]` in order to get the vertical spacing looking right.

Comment: `Rasterize[..., "BoundingBox"]` and `Rasterize[..., "RasterSize"]` may be of interest.

Comment: Nice work Simon. +1

Comment: Thanks @Szabolcs - it is of interest! And thanks Mr.Wizard.

Comment: this is great - thank you for the quick response

Comment: Not a problem @gamma. If you're happy with the answer, press the checkmark button at the top left of the answer. Also, maybe submit a request to Wolfram Research for a proper extensible circumflex glyph...